# What is the most efficient way to compute a rolling median on appengine?

Tags: google-app-engine

Since there is no app engine api that offers something like the Redis atomic list, I'm left wondering how to implement a cost effective rolling median.

I'm already receiving ~15 data points per second, so writing them all to the data store using a deferred task isn't an option unless they dramatically lower the writes cost.

[Gilberto Torrezan Filho](https://plus.google.com/u/0/117137338125512395261/posts) has suggested using backends and doing it all in memory.
I'm pretty sure this can work but it does feel like a workaround.

Has anyone found a super elegant solution?

Edit:
Storing the metrics is not an option, the volume is too high and quickly growing.
The prohibitive datastore write pricing rules out any solution that would involve permanent storage.
The rolling median is accessed by other requests at a rate even higher than the one at which data comes in.
Therefore, the median needs to be in sync with current values.

Comment: I think the answer will require a bit more specifics on what you're computing. Do you need to use the data from all time? How quickly/often do you need it? etcetc.

Comment: One method to compute a rolling median in a high-rate streaming environment is to sample the data regularly, rather than recording every point. Could that work for you?

Comment: A deferred write strategy is simple, maintains the integrity of your data during runtime, and allows you to distribute your writes.